# If 30! = 2652528598121a10586363088b80000000, what is a and b?

Tags: number-theory

I generally see these kinds of problems in math competitions. I was wondering how you could efficiently find out the values of a and b, and if there is a general rule for doing this with other factorials and digits?

Comment: Hint: $9\mid (30!)$ and $11\mid (30!)$

Comment: use divisibility test of 3 and 11.

Comment: This is a rather fun question which I know I've seen on this site before... but admittedly, searching for it is very difficult because I can't remember which factorial appeared in the question or which digits were replaced by $a$ and $b$.  The end result is of course that it doesn't really matter which positions $a$ and $b$ were in or which factorial was used since the technique is the same in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

Using divisibility tests fof 3,9,11 will not give independent equations for $a$ and $b$ because these digits arexseparared by 12(= an even number) positions.  Using divisibiliy by 7 or 13 fails to break the logjam because the separation is also a multiple of 3.

To get off center, use the fact that $30!$ will have 26 factors of 2 but only 7 factors of 5.  Therefore the last four digits before the terminal zeroes will be a multiple of 16 forcing $b=4$ (the numbers $8808$ and $8888$ are eight times odd numbers).  Now you can use divisibility by 11 to get a sure solution for $a$.